# Reducir la pantalla y reducir el menú horizontal

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando un menú horizontal para mi página, pero al reducir el tamaño de la pantalla para hacer que la página sea responsive, per el menú no se hace más pequeño, sino que se amontonan unos con otros. He probado algunas cosas pero ninguna ha dado resultado.

He buscado información en varios sitios pero sigo sin comprender que he hecho mal, os adjunto el código original.
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

*He añadido lo que he realizado en otros intentos y no funcionaba*

```html
<html>
  <style>   
    .menuhorizontal{
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px auto;
      background-color: ;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .menuhorizontal ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .menuhorizontal ul li {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
    .menuhorizontal li {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 3px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    a {
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
    li:hover {
      background-color: none;
    }
    .active {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: Black;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 100px) {
      .menuhorizontal {
         width: 25%;
       }
     }

  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="menuhorizontal">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" class="active">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="1.html">Quienes Somos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="2.html">Nuestras Actvidades</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uso de media querys en CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Lo que haces, es sobre-escribir estilos, dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla, generalmente su ancho.

Comment: ¿Y qué distribución deben de tener y a qué tamaño de pantalla?

Comment: Hay un par de templates para tamaños de pantalla, pero el resto se los das tu a tu comodidad

Comment: @BetaM pues lo que busco es que se queden horizontalmente pero reduzcan en tamaño

Comment: @Excorpion lo he probado pero algo he de haber hecho mal porque no hay ningún cambio

Comment: @Fst0 eso que hayas intentado agregalo a la pregunta por favor

Comment: @BetaM acabo de actualizar la pregunta

Comment: @Fst0 si lo veo, lo estás aplicando bien, pero los tamaños incorrectos. Recuerda que el media query toma el ancho de la pantalla. Ahora mismo le estás diciendo que cuando el ancho sea entre 0 y 100px, el tamaño del menu será de 25%. Lo que no se aprecia de ningun modo, ya que es muy pequeño ese ancho

Comment: @Fst0 puedo hacer una propuesta de respuesta pero para esto considera: ¿en serio siempre el menú debe estar horizontal? lo digo por que habrá pantalla donde no sea eso cómodo para el usuario y francamente si vas a hacer responsive entonces es para ajustar esos detalles y facilitar la navegación

Answer (score 0):

Una buena idea para visualizar los cambios que haces
es añadir color a los contenedores, en este caso al menu.
Luego, dentro de cada media query, debes ir estilizando la pagina web.

```css
.menuhorizontal{
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px auto;
      background-color: ;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .menuhorizontal ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .menuhorizontal ul li {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
    .menuhorizontal li {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 3px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    a {
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: blue;
    }
    li:hover {
      background-color: none;
    }
    .active {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: Black;
    }
    
     
     @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      .menuhorizontal {
         width: 50%;
         background-color: blue;
       }
     }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .menuhorizontal {
         width: 25%;
         background-color: red;
       }
     }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="menuhorizontal">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" class="active">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="1.html">Quienes Somos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="2.html">Nuestras Actvidades</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```